# python-plotly : add a scatter using x0/dx and y0/dy

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

after reading [plotly's reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-x0), I understood that rather than giving a list of point to draw a line, I could just give a point of origin and steps for x and y axes.

Then I tried this pretty basic first attempt:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
f = go.Figure()
f.add_trace(go.Scatter(x0=1, dx=1, y0=2, dy=1))
f.show(renderer='browser')
```

A browser window opens with a graph in it, but it is void. And I get no error message. Surprisingly, I found nothing online to help me.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I don't understand from Plotly's reference ? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a bit confusing in the docs, but the `x0`/`dx` pattern only works if you're providing `y`(and vice versa `y0`/`dy` only makes sense if you're providing `x`). They're basically shortcuts for providing data-free vectors.

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x0=10, dx=2, y=[1,3,2,4]))
fig.show()
```

is equivalent to providing `x=[10,12,14,16]` instead of `x0`/`dx`, but only in the presence of `y`.

To draw a straight line, you can use the [`layout.shapes` API](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-shapes) like this:

```
fig.update_layout(shapes=[dict(type="line", x0=11, x1=14, y0=3, y1=4)])
```

Comment: Thanks ! It is much clearer now, and as you mentioned it, much clearer than the doc.